# C# 'echo?/literal?' variable name as class instance

Tags: c#

I have a C# program I am developing.

```
String customerReference = String.Concat(firstName, lastName);
Customer customerReference  = new Customer(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);
```

I want to take the 'literal' (if thats the right word) value of customerReference to name the instance of the class customer.

As I am unfamiliar with the syntax of the C# language my question may seen confusing, but hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Whats your question? You shouldnt have a string AND a class definition AND a Customer object with same name. Do you have a customerReference class defined?

Comment: What do you mean by 'naming the instance'? Is this `Customer` class something you wrote or is it defined outside your program?

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to achieve here, it's not possible this way! Provide us with a little more code, so we can have an idea of what you want out of your code. :)

Comment: Sounds like he almost wants the address in memory of the object as a unique identifier? I'm not sure, but it sounds unnecessary.

Comment: Am I understanding you right that you want to have the `Customer` variable named what is the _content_ of customerReference? Like, if firstName is "John" and lastname is "Doe" the next line will be `Customer JohnDoe = new Customer(...)`. Because thats not really possible.

Comment: I recommend to read a C# book or C# tutorials to get at least a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve `Customer` instances *by name* maybe a `Dictionary<string, Customer>` is what you are looking for:

```
var customerMap = new Dictionary<string, Customer>();
string customerKey = firstName + lastName;
customerMap.Add(customerKey, customerReference);

//..
Customer c = customerMap[customerKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a customer class and store the customer reference it that:

```
String customerReference = String.Concat(firstName, lastName);
Customer customerReference  = new Customer(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, customerReference);
```

By trying to create the name of the class you'd like to create based on a reference you've generated you're opening yourself up for trouble. For example, what would you do it the class which corresponds to the customer reference doesn't exist..?

If you really really really do want to to this then you'll need to use reflection. Take a look at the [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable with same name `customerReference` a second time in the same scope if you tried to do that.